# Transpose the row data to column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have below a list of data(Sample data) in a single column in multiple rows in excel. I would like to categorize data into multiple columns like Type, Amount, Address, Beds, Bath, Parking, Area, and dwelling type.

Example please review below image.

***Data is like below image***
[image]

***Would like to format***

[image]

***Sample data:***

```
Sold by private treaty 04 Apr 2022
$755,000
2/13 Bank Street , WOLLONGONG NSW 2500
2 Beds 1 Bath 1 Parking 679m²
Townhouse
Sold by private treaty 04 Apr 2022
Benjamin Sayers
$585,000
15/50-52 Keira Street , WOLLONGONG NSW 2500
2 Beds 1 Bath 1 Parking
Apartment / Unit / Flat
Sold by private treaty 01 Apr 2022
$975,000
201/38 Atchison Street , WOLLONGONG NSW 2500
3 Beds 2 Baths 1 Parking
Apartment / Unit / Flat
```

Help Much appreciated. Excel or power Query.

Thanks and be safe.

Comment: Have you tried copy paste.special transpose? what happened? Or consider index(0 with match(0 driven by the "sold by private treaty" to delimit start / stop. Have you tried recording a macro and doing an example to see what it gives?

Comment: Why is there no line break in the third section? Has the pattern changed?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803748/transpose-data-based-on-the-proper-pattern

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried.  Please edit your question to include the rules you use to determine which groups of lines go together.

Comment: Well, I usually do with conditional formate, text that contains and is filtered by color, copy paste into a new column. this is taking a long time. Happy to accept any alternative methods which are easy and efficient. All I need is the price, address, bed, bath, parking, and sold. That's all.@solar Mike @horseyride,@Ron Rosenfeld. Data rows numbers might differ some times, that's the reason I did not use vba x number of rows select to transpose instead I am using text contain and some key letters and numbers. example for address I am taking 2500, amount I am taking 000, like wise. then filter

Comment: @RonRosenfeld- please read the above method.

Comment: @SolarMike I usually try conditional formatting. please review the above comment

Comment: your sample data looks double grouped, but what do I know. Please review your sample data. Are you missing a row break? Why is there no line break in the third section? Has the pattern changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started with your data in Excel as Table1. I assumed that Benjamin Sayers is the buyer of the second property, which indicates that some properties would have listed buyers and some would not. Because I assumed some would have buyers, that meant I had to account for the missing fields (lines from your data set) in the records without listed buyers.

The code below turns this:
[image]

into this:
[image]

Here's the code.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type any}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if Text.StartsWith(Text.From([Column1]),"Sold") then [Index] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Custom"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table [Column1=any, Index=number, Custom=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom.1", each if Table.RowCount([AllData]) < 6 then Table.InsertRows([AllData], 1,{Record.FromList(List.Repeat({""},Table.ColumnCount([AllData])),Table.ColumnNames([AllData]))}) else [AllData]),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.2", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Custom.1], "ColIndex", 0, 1, Int64.Type)),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom.3", each Table.Transpose(Table.SelectColumns([Custom.2],"Column1"))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"Custom.3"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.3" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom.3", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Custom.3",{{"Column1", "Type"}, {"Column2", "Seller?"}, {"Column3", "Amount"}, {"Column4", "Address"}, {"Column5", "BBP"}, {"Column6", "Dwelling Type"}}),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "BBP", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"BBP.1", "BBP.2", "BBP.3", "BBP.4"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"BBP.1", "Beds"}, {"BBP.2", "Baths"}, {"BBP.3", "Parking"}, {"BBP.4", "Area"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1"
```

I didn't spend much time polishing it. I figured I could at least get you started.